# Losing Wifi on 12.04, no way to get it back?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, eeepc

I am running 12.04 on an Asus EEEPC 1201n.  Regularly, wifi connection is lost and there seems to be no way to get it back without a reboot.  The same machine booted on WIN7 never fails.

I am at a loss, any ideas?

output from lspci :

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN     Controller (rev 10)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the wireless driver may be your problem which may be fixed in each new release of the kernel so I would recommend trying Ubuntu 12.10 to see if that helps...

Also here is a link for the latest 3.7 version of the kernel for 12.10:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-37-under.html