# Wifi sometimes dies, I can't get it back up (21.10)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I am having a problem similar to this question:
[Losing Wifi on 12.04, no way to get it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230182/losing-wifi-on-12-04-no-way-to-get-it-back)

On a machine where the problem doesn't manifest with windows and even in other machines, my wifi just randmly dies multiple times a day. there is no warning, sometimes it works for hours, sometimes in minutes but eventually it is guaranteed to happen. Wether the machine is iddle or working doesn't matter.

lspci output:

```
6:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

The only way I have found to fix it is rebooting. I have also tried resetting the network manager with systemctl but that doesn't fix it.

The wifi dying is not that much of an issue, but having to reboot to fix it is a chore, is there a way to emulate restarting the computer but only in so far as the wifi/network adapters are concerned? just so that I don't have to re-open every program I am using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command so we can identify your WiFi chipset. Solutions are hardware dependent, there isn't a "generic" solution. I suspect this is happening due to some power saving settings.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: I do. And this doesn't seem to happen in windows.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them. See my initial answer for some quick things that you can check. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: All i managed to check was the BIOS and the problem was not fixed. Time constraints prevent me from tampering too much, espeically the ubuntu suggestion. Creating the live boot USB and tampering with the file system will take time I don;t currently have.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**Ubuntu file system check**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**BIOS**

- Make sure that Secure Boot is disabled.

Then reboot into Ubuntu and retest.